# Make //repeat command correct length node & discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Currently for my discord bot I am trying to make a repeat command for me and my friends but the issue is since I'm new to discord.js and node I don't know any good alternatives to "startswith", what this means is while the "//repeat @user" command works, "//repeattesttext @user" also does the same thing. Is there any way to prevent this? Here is my code:

```
if (!msg.guild) return;
    if (msg.content.startsWith('//repeat')) {
        if (msg.member.roles.cache.has("744347114255155201")) {
            if (!active4) {
                const user = msg.mentions.users.first();
                if (user) {
                    const memb = msg.guild.member(user);
                    if (memb) {
                        if (active4) {
                            active4 = false;
                            msg.channel.send("Repeat Deactivated.")
                        } else {
                            id2 = memb.id
                            active4 = true
                            msg.channel.send("Repeat Activated")
                        }
                    }

                }
            } else {
                active4 = false
                msg.channel.send("Repeat Deacivated.")
            }
            return
        } else {
            msg.channel.send("You don't have RBLX permissions.")
            return
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated and since I'm new if you can please explain how your code works. Even if you can't I'll still be grateful for an answer of any kind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking if the string starts with `//repeat`, you should check if the first word is equal to that.
This can be achieving by separating the `msg.content` in an array containing its words.

`msg.content.split(' ')` gives that array.

`msg.content.split(' ')[0] === '//repeat'` is the if statement you are looking for.